# Location of field definition file in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What is the location of the field definition file in Sharepoint 2010 filesystem? I am looking for the Field ID of a field which I want to reference in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check TEMPLATE\FEATURES\fields in the 14 hive.

Most fields are found in fieldswss.xml, but some additional fields are found in fieldswss2.xml and fieldswss3.xml.

Note that out of the box content type definitions are found in TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ctypes (you didn't ask about that, but I often look at those files together, so I thought I'd mention it as well).